# Android Braintree Integration Pay with Paypal

Tags: android, braintree-sandbox

I am just going through the Braintreepayments "Get Started" page. This is a very simple tutorial. A few lines of code in both client and server, in my case Android and PHP. I started BraintreePaymentActivity.

Intent intent = new Intent(this, BraintreePaymentActivity.class);    intent.putExtra(BraintreePaymentActivity.EXTRA_CLIENT_TOKEN,token);
startActivityForResult(intent, 100);

When i am clicking on paypal and enter correct paypal credential. than Activity close and below exception and message Occure.

E/ERROR﹕ com.braintreepayments.api.dropin.EXTRA_ERROR_MESSAGE => com.braintreepayments.api.exceptions.UnexpectedException: Merchant account not found; with result code 3.

Please help!

Comment: I want to get nonce of correct paypal credential.

Comment: Can anyone please point me out if there is any steps or doc I missed out to check?